# How to write an R function or loop that will print every third number or nth number in [1, 100]?

Tags: r

I am trying to write a function in R which will print every 3rd number in [1,100]; this is what I have tried, but this doesn't produce every third number, it produces every number

```
x <- c(100)
question.1 <- function (x){
out <- seq(x)
 return(out)
}
question.1(x)
```

Am I missing something? Any help you can offer would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: the answer below or `seq(3,100,3)` or `(1:100)[1:100 %% 3 == 0]` and what made you think this would produce every third number only?

Comment: see  "fizzbuzz"  on the 'net

Answer (score 5):

Use the modulo operator (%%) to obtain every nth value from 1:100 like this:

```
nth <- function(x,n){
  x[x%%n==0]
}
```

For example:

```
x <- 1:100
nth(x,7)
[1]  7 14 21 28 35 42 49 56 63 70 77 84 91 98
```

Answer (score 4):

Use indexing with `[` and the recycling of short vectors:

```
seq(100)[c(F,F,T)]
## [1]  3  6  9 12 15 18 21 24 27 30 33 36 39 42 45 48 51 54 57 60 63 66 69 72 75 78 81 84 87 90 93 96 99
```

Answer (score 2):

Excellent answers have already been posted; this is just one further simple alternative:

```
start <- 1 # defines the initial number you want to select
step <- 3 # difference between subsequent numbers 
seq(start, 100, by=step)
#[1]   1   4   7  10  13  16  19  22  25  28  31  34  37  40  43  46  49  52  55  58  61  64  67  70  73  76  79  82  85  88  91  94  97 100
```

Comment: This is the obvious alternative for a regular sequence, but if the vector isn't sorted and you can't sort it, then it wouldn't work.

Comment: @Molx Thank you for your comment. Although I agree with your statement, I don't understand the criticism in this specific case. The OP is looking for a solution that "will print every 3rd number in [1,100]", and I think that this is exactly what can be achieved with these three lines (that could as well be written as a single line).

Comment: I believe that the question would have been phrased differently if the OP was trying to extract a specific subset with the size 1/3 from a given, unsorted set of numbers between 1 and 100.

Answer (score 1):

Just wrapping Matthew's solution in a general nth function:

```
nth <- function(x, n) x[c(rep(FALSE, n-1), TRUE)]

nth(1:100, 5)

# [1]   5  10  15  20  25  30  35  40  45  50  55  60  65  70  75  80  85  90  95 100
```

Or even using an operator-style:

```
`%nth%` <- function(x, n) x[c(rep(FALSE, n-1), TRUE)]

seq(100) %nth% 5
```